# Send tomcat logs with syslog-ng in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, syslog-ng

I am trying to setup syslog-ng to send tomcat logs (as well as all the other system logs) to a log server but it doesn't seem to be working, this is the line I have:

`destination d_tomcat { file("/opt/tomcat/logs/*.log"); };`

And then of course this:

`log { source(s_src); destination(d_net); };`

and this

`destination d_net { tcp("x.x.x.x" port(1514) log_fifo_size(1000)); };`

Comment: configure tomcat to send the logs to syslog https://www.badllama.com/content/tomcat-7-logging-syslog-log4j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a source that reads the tomcat logs, and sends them over to your log server. So assuming that tomcat logs into a file, you need something like:

`source s_file { file("/opt/tomcat/logs/tomcat.log" multi-line-mode(indented)); };`

(Note that the "/opt/tomcat/logs/*.log" will not currently work in syslog-ng Open Source Edition, because it does not yet support wildcards in the source - you have to specify the file to read)
Then the destination:

`destination d_net { tcp("x.x.x.x" port(1514) log_fifo_size(1000)); };`

See the [syslog-ng documentation](https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/reference-source-file.html#idp2094736) for more details.

And the log statement to connect them:

```
log { source(s_file); destination(d_net); };
```